# Group Policy Folder Redirection deleted my Documents folder

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, folder-redirection

OK so i have a server 2008 R2 server with AD.
I created a group policy for folder redirection of the documents folder and applied it.
I logged on with my work machine (windows 7 32 bit) and the folder copied across to the server fine.  (i checked on my PC and on the server).

I shut down the PC, went home and logged on via VPN. I accessed the server via remote desktop (using the same account as i used on my work PC) then logged off.

Today I've come back in and logged onto my work PC to find that all my documents folder has been deleted (i know it's deleted and not just lost because I've just undeleted it). This issue has only affected me.

I'm assuming that this has something to do with me logging on via VPN/RD on my home PC (as no one else can do this and no one else has lost any data).

Why is this happening and how can i stop it. I need to get this fixed otherwise we obviously cannot use folder redirection if it will delete user's files every time they log on via vpn

Comment: I believe we have a customer with this problem too. They're running a system remotely over Citrix. Were you able to resolve this?